# How to decorate a JavaScript class constructor when using non-legacy decorators?

Tags: javascript, javascript-decorators

I have the following class:

```js
@log
class Example {
  constructor(name, age) {
    console.log("Example constructor", name, age);
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

And this `@log` decorator when using legacy decorators:

```js
function log(Class) {
  return class extends Class {
    constructor(...args) {
      console.log("log", args);
      super(...args);
    }
  };
}
```

```js
// .babelrc
// ...
      "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
        // ...
      ]
// ...
```

The above setup works well, and the following code:

```js
const example = new Example("Graham", 34);
```

Outputs:

```
log (2) ["Graham", 34]
Example constructor Graham 34
```

Now, how can I achieve the same result when using non-legacy decorators, i.e.:

```js
// .babelrc
// ...
      "plugins": [
        [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
          { "decoratorsBeforeExport": false }
        ],
        // ...
      ]
// ...
```

How can I implement `@log` so that it works in the same way as with legacy decorators?

```js
function log(...args) {
  const [descriptor] = args;
  const { kind, elements } = descriptor;

  const newElements = elements.concat({
    kind: "method",
    placement: "prototype",
    key: "constructor",
    descriptor: {
      value: (...args) => {
        // I have tried this but it doesn't work...
        console.log("log", args);
      },
      configurable: true,
      writable: true,
      enumerable: true,
    },
  });

  return {
    kind,
    elements: newElements,
  };
}
```

I have tried the code above but it didn't work. The problem is that I do not have a reference to the target when using non-legacy decorators. Do you know if there is a way to achieve the same behaviour as with the legacy ones?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "reference to the target"? Notice that you cannot use arrow functions as constructors.

Comment: `reference to the target`: When I use legacy decorators, I get a `target` parameter which is the class I am decorating (`Class` in my example). I can then return a `class extends Class {}`  and wrap/decorate the original constructor as I did my legacy decorators example. But how can I achieve the same with non-legacy decorators when the parameter I receive is a `descriptor` object with `const { kind, elements } = descriptor;` ? Thank you!

Comment: Isn't this still [the old proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/blob/master/previous/METAPROGRAMMING.md)? With the current proposal, I think you're looking for the [`@wrap` decorator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators#wrap)

Comment: Is the old proposal deprecated? Or is it still under construction? How would you use `@wrap` with `@log` in order to achieve the same result as with legacy decorators? I would basically need to perform some operations `before`, `after` the decorated constructor of `Example`, maybe even return an instance completely different from `new Example`, i.e. without calling `super`, all of this when I use `@log` in non-legacy mode...

Comment: @Bergi I have found out that non-legacy decorators have something called a `finisher`: https://babeljs.io/blog/2018/09/17/decorators#decorator-functions-arguments `They can also create additional properties and define a function (a finisher) which is run on the decorated class` Do you know how to use this finisher function? I couldn't find the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer, thanks to loganfsmyth on the [BabelJS Slack channel](https://babeljs.slack.com/).

You have to return an object with a property called `finisher` wrapping the class, e.g.:

```js
function log(...args) {
  const [descriptor] = args;
  const { kind, elements } = descriptor;

  return {
    kind,
    elements,
    finisher: (Class) => {
      return class extends Class {
        constructor(...args) {
          console.log("log", args);
          super(...args);
        }
      };
    }
  };
}
```

Then this code when using non-legacy decorators:

```
@log
class Example {
  constructor(name, age) {
    console.log("Example constructor", name, age);
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}

const example = new Example("Graham", 34);
```

Outputs:

```
log (2) ["Graham", 34]
Example constructor Graham 34
```

As with legacy decorators.

It was difficult to find the answer because this feature of non-legacy decorators is not documented on [@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators).